# xpath of Self-closing XML tag using mysql ExtractValue

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath, extract-value

Is there any way to know whether the self-closing(`<privacy />`) XML tag exist inside the xml, using the `mysql` `ExtractValue` xpath function.

The xml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <privacy />
        <firstName>Brian</firstName>
        <lastName>Schultz</lastName>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

SP is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `xpath1`(IN xml VARCHAR(10000))
BEGIN
SELECT  ExtractValue(xml, '//employee/firstName/text()');
/*SELECT  ExtractValue(xml, '//employee/privacy');
 SELECT  ExtractValue(xml, '//employee/privacy/text()');*/
END
```

`ExtractValue(xml, '//employee/privacy');` & `ExtractValue(xml, '//employee/privacy/text()');` always return empty space in the result with or without the self-closing tag.

The xml is coming from external app. Any help is great..

Comment: I suppose "SELECT  ExtractValue(xml, '//employee/privacy/test()')" is a type? Probably you meant: "SELECT  ExtractValue(xml, '//employee/privacy/text()')", to see if it contains text()?

Comment: ys..typing mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the 8.0 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) you could use count like this:

```
SELECT  ExtractValue(xml, 'count(//employee/privacy)'
```